# c++ function input error

Tags: c++, function, input

I'm writing a monte carlo simulation and my 1st function is an input but it keeps kicking back an error stating that the variable "is not declared in this scope", I tried adding the variable type in the main and it still doesn't build. I then added the variable type in the function (cin>>rounds to cin>> int rounds), and the error changed but still doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what's going on and what I need to do get the function to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int getInput();
using namespace std;

int main (void){
    //set up random
    srand(time(NULL));

    //1st function
    getInput();
```

}

```
/* @description gets a valid user input
* @param output and input
*/
    int getInput(){
        cout<<"enter amount of rounds";
        cin>> rounds; **(error is here on line 24 ("rounds not declared in 
this scope")**
}
```

Comment: i can't believe you really forgot to declare the variable because that would be quite obvious. could it be you just forgot to mention it in your question? if you really forgot it that would explain why it couldn't be found.

Comment: Please don't post paraphrased portions of errors; that is not useful. Post the whole thing, including the line and column number that your compiler gives you. I'm voting to close this as not including enough information to form a useful answer, since you didn't show any indication of how many files you're compiling and how, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to declare the variable (as int or long whatever desired) in the function as given below:

```
int getInput(){
        int rounds;
        cout<<"enter amount of rounds";
        cin>> rounds; **(error is here on line 24 ("rounds not declared in 
this scope")**
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If ok - then kindly accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark button on the answer. Thanks

Comment: @BabyGroot Your function implementation is likely to crash the program.

Comment: @user0042: could you please elaborate on what's the correct way as this is probably the basic answer that would fix this code.

Comment: @BabyGroot What does this function return? Also `**(error is here on line 24 ("rounds not declared in 
this scope")**` won't compile at all.

Comment: @user0042: `**(error is here on line 24 ("rounds not declared in this scope")**` - I think this is just a comment by the person who asked the question to indicate the error. About returning, maybe there is some part of the user probably gave a simplistic question to focus on the problem - I am sure there will be much more code here.

Answer (score 4):

> "is not declared in this scope"

This means that where you try to use your variable (i.e. `rounds`), it is not known. Declaring it inside `main` wouldn't help, since the scope of `getInput` != scope of `main`.

You have 4 possibilities:

1. Declare in `main` and send as an argument *[will be in scope for `main` + `getInput`]*
2. Declare inside `getInput` *[will be in scope for `getInput`]*
3. Declare as global (i.e. above `main`) *[will be in scope for everyone]*
4. Add `extern` and declare wherever you like *[will be in scope for everyone]*

*Clarification: "will be in scope for..." means "from here on..."*

---

**Here are code snippets to show your options:**

```
/* 1st option */
void foo(int x){
    x = 1;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    foo(x);
    return 0;
}

/*************************************/

/* 2nd option */
void foo(){
    int x;
    x = 1;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
} 

/*************************************/

/* 3rd option */
int x;

void foo(){
    x = 1;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}

/*************************************/

/* 4th option */
void foo(){
    extern int x;
    x = 1;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
int x;
```

---

In the I would change your code into something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int getInput();
using namespace std;

int main (void){
    ...
    int in = getInput();
    ...
}

/* @description gets a valid user input
* @param output and input
*/
    int getInput(){
        int rounds;
        cout << "enter amount of rounds";
        cin >> rounds; 
        return rounds; // dont forget to return :)
}
```

Comment: Great - thanks - much clarity